# How can each user make a choice in a sequencial way

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Fantasy Soccer Rails app and i'm trying to add a feature, which is to each user make a draft choice, one user at a time, one after the other; how can i make that?
A user creates a lineItem refering to each player selected to save him to his personal squad.
Here is some of the code that i think is regarding the feature but more is needed please tell me.
Thanks

> user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

 has_one :squad
end
```

> users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def update
    skip_authorization
    @user = current_user
    @user.update(user_params)
    redirect_to profile_path
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :mobile, :drft_pass, :drft_shortlist)
  end

  has_one :squad
end
```

> line_item.rb

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :squad
end
```

> line_items_controller.rb

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_line_item, only: [:destroy]
before_action :set_player, only: [:create]



    def create
        #@player_id = @player
        #chosen_player = @player
        #@squad_id = @squad
        #current_squad = @current_squad


        
        if LineItem.where(squad_id: params[:squad_id]).where(player_id: params[:player_id]).count > 0

            message = 'This player is already on your Squad'
           
        elsif


            LineItem.where(player_id: params[:player_id]).present?

            message = 'This player is already selected by other Coach'
  
        else

            @line_item = LineItem.new
            @player = Player.find(params[:player_id])
            @squad = Squad.find(params[:squad_id])
            @line_item.squad = @squad
            @line_item.player = @player
            @line_item.save
            message = 'Success. The player was added to your Squad'

       
           
        end
            redirect_to players_path
            flash[:notice] = message
    end

    def destroy   
        @line_item.destroy
        redirect_to user_squad_path(current_user.id, :squad_id)
    end

    private

    def line_item_params
        params.require(:line_item).permit(:player_id, :squad_id)
    end

    def set_line_item
        @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_player
        @player = Player.find(params[:player_id])
    end

    

end
```

> player.rb

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  include PgSearch::Model
  pg_search_scope :search_by_full_name, against: [:name, :club, :pos]
end
```

> players_controller.rb

```
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
  #before_action :set_players, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
    if params[:term]
      @players = Player.search_by_full_name(params[:term]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
    else
      @players = Player.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
    end
  end

  def show
    @player = Player.find(params[:id])
    
  end

  private

  def player_params
    params.require(:player).permit()
  end

  def set_player
    @player = Player.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

> squad.rb

```
class Squad < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :photo

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :players, through: :line_items
  
  validates :name, presence: true

end
```

> squads_controller.rb

```
class SquadsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    #before_action :set_squad

    def show
        
    end

    def new
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @squad = Squad.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @squad = Squad.new(squad_params)
        @squad.user = @user
        if @squad.save
           redirect_to user_squad_path(current_user.id, @squad)
           flash[:notice] = 'Success. Your squad was created'
        else
            render "new"
            flash[:notice] = 'Squad not created; please try again'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @squad = Squad.find(params[:squad_id])
    end

    def update
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @squad = Squad.find(params[:id])
        @squad.update(squad_params)
        redirect_to user_squad_path(current_user.id, @squad)
    end




    def destroy
        @squad = Squad.find(params[:squad_id])    
        @squad.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private

    def set_squad
        @squad = @current_squad
    end
    
    def squad_params
        params.require(:squad).permit(:name, :sigla, :photo)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so there's a lot going on here - far too much for us to help with in a single question. Saying "This doesn't work, please fix it" isn't going to get you useful answers. What, exactly, isn't working? How isn't it working? And what exactly do you want help with?

Some easy tips to start you off, though. First, you could make a lot better use of Rails built-in helpers. For example, in your `line_items_controller`, try something like this:

```rb
def create
  line_item = LineItem.find_by(player_id: line_item_params[:player_id])
  if line_item.present?
    message = if line_item.squad_id == current_user.squad_id
                'This player is already on your Squad'
              else
                'This player is already selected by other Coach'
              end
  else
    @line_item = LineItem.new
    @line_item.squad = current_user.squad
    @line_item.player = Player.find(line_item_params[:player_id])
    message = if @line_item.save
                'Success. The player was added to your Squad'
              else
                "Error - couldn't save your selection"
              end
  end
  flash[:notice] = message
  redirect_to players_path
end
```

Notice that using current_user.squad will return the related record, as will squad.line_items return the related records. This means (a) you don't have to write queries and (b) you'll always protect yourself against accidentally allowing a user to access records they shouldn't have access to (like other people's squads).

I've also switched around the logic of your `if` block to reduce the number of times you query the database. First, find the LineItem containing this player (using `find_by` rather than `where` because, presumably, there should be only one such record because a Player should only be in one Squad). If there are any records, check to see whether the squad for that LineItem matches the current_user's squad and adjust the message depending.

Then, assign the Player to the user's Squad if they're available, pretty much as you did before. You're not using strong params, even though you've defined the required method in e.g. the line_items_controller. You'll note that I've inserted this reference into the example above. The big change to this block is that it's best to avoid using the `squad` parameter because (presumably) each user can only create LineItems for their own squad! So I've swapped this for `current_user.squad`.

And note that you need to set your flash message before redirecting - that's effectively the end of your method.

That gives you one (!) of your methods cleaned up and hopefully doing what you want. But, overall, as I said, you're probably going to have to tell us exactly what the problem is that you're having.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs... I knew that the code isn't very DRY but it's still in a early stage, i'm planning on doing some clean up and for sure going to use your ideas... But everything is working fine, my presented issue was more related to add that next feature of each user makes a draft choice, one each time, but don't know where to start

Comment: It's less about DRYness and more about making effective use about Rails helpers. And I think you need to be a lot clearer about your actual problem - it sounds from the question like the code isn't working, rather than your wanting advice  about how to add a new feature (and it's not at all clear to be, even knowing that, what your actual problem is!).

Comment: Ok... I'll refactor the question and try to be a bit clearer on what i need, thanks... As i said, everything is working fine, just want to add that new feature

Comment: Sounds good. The key will be: (1) what is happening now; (2) what do you want to be different; and (3) which key bits of code are involved. Ideally, also, what you've already tried and what *exactly* is going wrong.